# Summing values based on type then on Month

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a `List<Object>` where Object contains Name, Month, Type, Value.

is it possible to sum all the Value based on type, and then based on month?

I am using .NET 3.0 in VB.NET
I was doing withe like 4 For loops, but its taking a while to run.
Is there a quicker way?

For clarification, I have something like this:

```
Name   | Month | Type | Value
-----------------------------
hello  | Jan   | A    | 1
hello  | Jan   | A    | 2
hello  | Jan   | B    | 2
hello  | Feb   | A    | 3
hello1 | Jan   | A    | 6
hello1 | Jan   | A    | 2
hello1 | Jan   | B    | 2
hello1 | Feb   | A    | 3
```

I want to produce it into this

```
Name   | Month | Type | Value
---------------------------
hello  | Jan   | A    | 3
hello  | Jan   | B    | 2
hello  | Feb   | A    | 3
hello1 | Jan   | A    | 8
hello1 | Jan   | B    | 2
hello1 | Feb   | A    | 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by “sum all the Value based on type, and then based on month”? How can you sum based on a month when all you’re left with is an array if `Value` sums (numbers, I presume).

Comment: `Value` is of datatype `double`.  I want to add all the `Value` for each type, and each type belongs to each month.

Comment: @Konrad: Updated the description to make myself clearer

Answer (score 1):

If LINQ is not possible:

You could use Dictionarys to hold the month-values and the type-values. So you only need one loop to fill all. Here is an example:

Foo is your object and FooType is your type:

```
Class Foo
    Public Enum FooType As Int32
        FirstType = 1
        SecondType = 2
        ThirdType = 3
        FourthType = 4
        FifthType = 5
    End Enum
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Month As Date
    Public Property type As FooType
    Public Property value As Double
End Class
```

load some sample-data:

```
Dim monthRnd As New Random(Date.Now.Millisecond)
Dim yearRnd As New Random(Date.Now.Millisecond)
Dim valueRnd As New Random(Date.Now.Millisecond)
Dim fooTypeRnd As New Random(Date.Now.Millisecond)
Dim allFoos As New List(Of Foo)
For i As Int32 = 1 To 1000
    Dim foo As New Foo
    foo.Name = i & ". Foo"
    foo.type = CType(fooTypeRnd.Next(1, 5), Foo.FooType)
    foo.Month = New Date(2000 + yearRnd.Next(0, 12), monthRnd.Next(1, 12), 1)
    foo.value = valueRnd.Next(1, 10000) * valueRnd.NextDouble()
    allFoos.Add(foo)
Next
```

Fill total value, grouped by type and by month:

```
Dim sumTotal As Double = 0D
Dim monthSums As New Dictionary(Of Date, Double)
Dim typeSums As New Dictionary(Of Foo.FooType, Double)
For Each f As Foo In allFoos
    sumTotal += f.value
    If typeSums.ContainsKey(f.type) Then
       typeSums(f.type) += f.value
    Else
       typeSums.Add(f.type, f.value)
    End If
    If monthSums.ContainsKey(f.Month) Then
       monthSums(f.Month) += f.value
    Else
       monthSums.Add(f.Month, f.value)
    End If
Next
```

Now you can access these values easily via Dictionary key.
For example:

```
 Dim feb2010Value As Double = 0d
 Dim feb2010 As New Date(2010, 2, 1)
 If monthSums.ContainsKey(feb2010) Then
     feb2010Value = monthSums(feb2010)
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m still not sure what you want but your example makes it seem as if you group by name *and* by month *and* by type at the same time.

Either way, that’s an aggregation into a group. The following should work.

```
Dim result = From obj In objects _
             Group obj By obj.Name, obj.Month, obj.Type Into _
             Value = Sum(obj.Value) _
             Select Name, Month, Type, Value
```

However, you shouldn’t use a `List(Of Object)` – use the correct object type instead.

(Untested, haven’t got VB handy so the actual syntax can deviate in small ways.)

Comment: Sorry forgive my stupidity, but say the list is called List<myObject>. I don't see how the above relates to the list.

Comment: @user159603 Well you didn’t provide a name for your list. ;-) I just called it `objects` – so the `From obj in objects` is meant to iterate over your list.

Comment: I mean I dont get the intellisense when I type in lstMyObjects and then add dot. Btw: Imean List<myObject> is called lstMyObjects

Comment: I mean I dont get the types in intellisense

Comment: @user159603 Not sure what’s causing this. Which version of VB are you using? The above is LINQ code and that’s been supported since VB9 (Visual Studio 2008). But you shouldn’t necessarily see anything interesting in IntelliSense: the above code doesn’t access members of `lstMyObjects` at all.

Comment: .NET 3.0. Surely when I press obj dot I should see Name, Month and Type?  where objects is  `List(of myObject)` not `myObject` right?

Comment: @user159603 Ah, correct. But according to Wikipedia Linq was released for .NET 3.5 so your version is indeed to old. Any chance of an upgrade? The 3.5 and 4.0 versions have *tons* new features. In the meantime, Tim’s dictionary solution might be the easiest route.